# How do I get the target directory in a script?

Tags: sbt

I am trying to get the target directory for modules in a multimodule project.  The challenge I have is that SBT's logging makes it hard to consume in a script.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
function sbt-target {
  sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true "project $1" 'show target' |
    tail -n1 |
    cut -c8-
}
```

I think this is very hackish as it knows about the **[INFO]** prefix (the **cut -c8-**) of each output line from SBT and about the fact that SBT's last line is the output I need (the **tail -n1**).

More problematic is that each invocation of **sbt-target** takes almost 11 seconds so invoking it for each module for a large number of modules in this project dominates the time.

How do I get the target directory in a script?

Comment: FYI, the `function` keyword is not POSIX-compliant, and neither is using dashes within function names -- also, bash doesn't promise in its documentation that the latter behavior will continue working, so taking advantage of it is risky. The portable way to declare a function is just `sbt_target() { ... }`

Comment: ...by the way, I _do_ use some bashisms in my answer. The difference is that (1) they're things bash's documentation guarantees will continue to work in future releases, and (2) they provide functional advantages over the equivalent POSIX-compliant code.

Comment: I've removed the bash tag since the question is really about SBT and not bash. Sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to SBT. In terms of bash best-practices, you might consider something more akin to the following:

```
sbt_target() {
  # declare locals as such
  local line version
  # iterate through all lines; later lines overwrite variable set by prior ones
  while read -r line; do
    version=${line#"[INFO] "} # strip undesired prefix if present
  done < <(sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true "project $1" 'show target')
  # emit result to stdout
  printf '%s\n' "$version"
}
```

Unlike the version relying on tail and cut, this does everything in-process within bash, and is thus more efficient (presuming that sbt's `show target` emits a relatively small amount of output).

Comment: Running `sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true "project example" 'show target'` takes 11 seconds so there's a very small amount of time lost to context switching on the pipeline.  This is really about SBT and not Bash.  Thank you for the advice though :)  I will keep it in mind for more complex Bash scripts.

Comment: Sorry for my incredibly late accept on this.  It's a legit answer as it makes the dependency on the **[INFO] ** prefix explicit.  It also taught me some things about Bash I didn't previously realize.  I meant to come back and accept this ages ago.  It's what I wound up using :)